# Risky Phone Plan

Tags: code-golf, clock

You have a phone plan that lets you talk 180 minutes a day. Every day that you go over your daily limit you have to pay a fine of **F = Me<sup>n</sup>**, where *M* is the number of minutes you went over and *n* is the number of days you have gone over (e.g if I went 20 minutes over the daily limit and it's my 2<sup>nd</sup> day going over, I have to pay 20*e<sup>2</sup> = 147.78).

You will be given a list of 12-hour clock times. Even-indexed times represent the start of a phone call, odd-indexed times represent the end of a phone call. Using this list find out how much money the person has to pay in fines.

## Notes

- Please use an approximation of *e* that is at least as accurate as 2.718
- You never need to round your answers or include a currency symbol.
- The first time in the list will always be an A.M (morning) time.
- Remember that in 12-hour time `1` comes after `12` (you can think of `12` as `0`).
- A day starts at 12:00 AM and ends at 11:59 PM
- If a number is lower than the previous time, then that means that it is in the opposite (A.M./P.M) time range.
- A call will never start in one day and end in another.

## Test Cases

```
10:30
2:30
5:30
6:30
```

This person made two phone calls in one day. One from 10:30 A.M. to 2:30 P.M., another from 5:30 P.M to 6:30 P.M. In total, they talked for 5 hours this day, going 120 minutes over the daily limit. Since it's their first offense, they have to pay 120*e = `$326.19` (yes, their phone plan is quite Draconic).

---

```
10:30
11:45
5:15
6:45
8:20
9:20
5:30
7:50
2:30
3:30
```

This person made several phone calls over 2 days. The first day they were on the phone from 10:30-11:45 A.M, 5:15-6:45 P.M., and 8:20-9:20 PM using a total of 225 minutes. That is an overage of 45 minutes. So their fine for the day is 45*e = $122.32.

The next day they talked from 5:30-7:50 A.M and 2:30-3:30 P.M., a total of 200 minutes. They went over by 20 minutes, and since it's their second offense they pay 20*e<sup>2</sup> = $147.78

You output their total fee as $122.32 + $147.78 = `$270.10`

---

```
10:30
11:30
6:30
7:30
9:45
11:00
10:25
11:25
8:45
9:45
6:00
8:00
2:30
4:30
```

- **Day 1:**

  - 10:30-11:30 A.M., 6:30-7:30 P.M., 9:45-11:00 P.M. = 195 minutes
  - Fee: 15*e = $40.77
- **Day 2:**

  - 10:25-11:25 A.M., 8:45-9:45 P.M. = 120 minutes
  - Fee: $0
- **Day 3:**

  - 6:00 - 8:00 A.M., 2:30-4:30 P.M. = 240 minutes
  - Fee: 60*e<sup>2</sup> = $443.34

Output: $40.77 + $0 + $443.34 = `$484.11`

Comment: This sounds a lot like [VerizonMath](https://xkcd.com/verizon/)

Comment: @user8 Yes, as you can see in the first test case.

Comment: Would the call log `8:00 9:00 7:00 6:00` be parsed as `Day 1 8:00AM - 9:00PM, Day 2 7:00AM - 6:00PM` or be invalid? If it's valid it would break the rule that *"If a number is lower than the previous time, then that means that it is in the opposite (A.M./P.M) time range"*.

Comment: @user8 no, the first part is parsed as 8-9 AM, the 2nd part is invalid bcuz it crosses from day 1 to day 2.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to write `Day 1 8:00AM - 9:00AM`. But thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 185 bytes

```perl
@c=map{s/(.+):(.+)/$1%12*60+$2/er}<>;while(@c){$s=shift@c;$e=shift@c;$p+=0>($k=$e-$s)?720+$k:$k;if($e>$c[0]||$k<0){if($m||!@c){$f+=0>($p-=180)?0:$p*exp++$d;$p=0}$m=!$m}}printf'$%.2f',$f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoJAFEX3/UVwRcfJfE5ooY35H9EibAZFjUGFAvXbTWvR5nC5cI5RbR3Oc5bL5m6Gznf2nMUrfARWINyIOISv2umcJq@irJWT5WxAJ7ui1H2WJ1D/abik1EEloTx07HIUi13FqJJSO1Ap8ivdxhHVmdiwXs04br89/TONJ4MTsQvFMK56G87xWLKSJjRyi2aaTFs@e23D2gtt76DnOaD4QBuxIlwRLfgA)